# Highlight simple row of numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I have a javascript loop and want to highlight some numbers

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
  $("#mydiv").append("<span>"+i+"</span>");
}
```

now i want to select 1,5,9,13,17... every 4th but beginning with 1 and highlight it. every second is easy:

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
  var bool = false;
  if(bool){
    $("#mydiv").append("<span>"+i+"</span>");
    bool = false;
  } else {
    $("#mydiv").append("<span class='highlight'>"+i+"</span>");
    bool = true;
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that people are recommending nth-child selectors for jQuery but not just straight-up nth-child styling via CSS.

In your stylesheet:

```css
#mydiv span:nth-child(4n-2) { background-color: yellow }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can make this with the nth-child selector. See this js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pJZkL/

```
$(function(){
    var ap = "";
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
        ap+="<span class='nr'>"+i+", </span>";
    }
    $("p").append(ap);
});
```

The logic for that is now in the CSS:

```
.nr{
    color: blue;
}
.nr:nth-child(4n-2){
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/muu2E/)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
  if(i%4==1){
    $("#mydiv").append("<span class="highlight">"+i+"</span>");
  } else {
    $("#mydiv").append("<span>"+i+"</span>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
$('#mydiv span:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i got your question correctly. From what i understand, the following loop should help you.

```
var inc = 1;
for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
  if(i !== inc ){
    $("#mydiv").append("<span>"+i+"</span>");
  } else {
    $("#mydiv").append("<span class="highlight">"+i+"</span>");
    inc += 4;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var pre = 0;
 for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
   if(i === 1 || (i-4) === pre ){
      $("#mydiv").append("<span class="highlight">"+i+"</span>");
      pre = i;
   } else {
      $("#mydiv").append("<span>"+i+"</span>");
   }
 }
```

This should do it. ive not tested it though.. Cheers